# Sorting several names with the `sort()` method in JS

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons, the first is named `btnClient` and the following is `btnSort`. When, I enter 3 names, I would like to sort alphabetically.

I have to use the method `sort()`but it doesn't work.

In HTML

```
<body >
  <h1>Exercise 13</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nameClient" size="30"  />
    <button id='btnClient'>Save client</button>
    <input type="text" id="listSort" size="30"  />
    <button id='btnSort'>List sort</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

In JS

```
var arrayClient = new Array();

var buttonClient = document.getElementById('btnClient');
var buttonDisplay = document.getElementById('btnSort');

buttonClient.addEventListener('click', addClient);
buttonDisplay.addEventListener('click', display);

function addClient(){

    var i = 0;

    arrayClient[i] = document.getElementById('nameClient');
    i = i + 1;

    document.getElementById('nameClient').value = ' ';
}

function display()
{   

    arrayClient.sort();

}
```

My `btnSort` button has a problem, nothing happening, even by clicking on button `btnSort`.

```js
var arrayClient = new Array();

var buttonClient = document.getElementById('btnClient');
var buttonDisplay = document.getElementById('btnSort');

buttonClient.addEventListener('click', addClient);
buttonDisplay.addEventListener('click', display);

function addClient(){

    var i = 0;

    arrayClient[i] = document.getElementById('nameClient');
    i = i + 1;

    document.getElementById('nameClient').value = ' ';
}

function display()
{   

    arrayClient.sort();

}
```

```html
    <html>
    
    <head>
    
      <script src="Thing.js" type="text/javascript">
      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
    </head>

     <body >
  <h1>Exercise 13</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nameClient" size="30"  />
    <button id='btnClient'>Save client</button>
    <input type="text" id="listSort" size="30"  />
    <button id='btnSort'>List sort</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use push method to add values to your array after clicking the bntClient button,

After clicking on sort you will see these values being sorted and displayed in the console.

Your second input is meaningless.

```js
const arrayClient = []

const buttonClient = document.getElementById('btnClient');
const buttonDisplay = document.getElementById('btnSort');
const firstInput = document.getElementById('nameClient');

buttonClient.addEventListener('click', addClient);
buttonDisplay.addEventListener('click', display);


function addClient() {
  arrayClient.push(firstInput.value.trim());
  firstInput.value = '';
}

function display() {
  arrayClient.sort();
  console.log(arrayClient);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="Thing.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Exercise 13</h1>
  <input type="text" id="nameClient" size="30" />
  <button id='btnClient'>Save client</button>
  <input type="text" id="listSort" size="30" />
  <button id='btnSort'>List sort</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```